# How do you use systemd's journalctl patterns

Tags: systemd, arch-linux, journald

I am trying to use `journalctl`'s pattern matching on `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIERS`. As an example, I have a ton of message tagged `sshd`:

```
$ journalctl -t sshd | wc -l
987
```

but if I try to use pattern matching to find them:

```
$ journalctl -t 'ssh*'
-- No Entries --
$ journalctl -t 'ssh.*'
-- No Entries --
```

The journalctl man page says patterns should work, but I can't find anything else about how patterns are used/defined in systemd.

```
$ man journalctl
....
-t, --identifier=SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER|PATTERN
       Show messages for the specified syslog identifier SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER,
       or for any of the messages with a "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" matched by PATTERN.
```

I'm running ArchLinux:

```
$ journalctl --version
systemd 225
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP
+GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

Comment: Based on discussions on IRC, it seems this is a bug (or an issues with the documentation). A bug has been [filed](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1256).

Comment: try this for realtime: journalctl -f | grep sshd

Comment: You can actually add multiple -t <identifier> if that suits you.

Comment: Opened another report for enabling pattern support for syslog identities: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/20457

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This was a [doc bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1256) that was closed when the typo in the `man` page was updated.

The bug report led to the following [comments in the code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/fd8d05e9b85c7973339e58d9bc1e5ccd4f5c98b7):

> We don't actually accept patterns, hence don't claim so.

As a workaround, you may be able to use `grep` as suggested in the comments to your question. Something like this:

```
journalctl | grep sshd
```

Comment: This missing feature or the bug is by design. Nice.

Answer (score 17):

journalctl -v 239 supports filtering with `-g`

From [journactl man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/journalctl.1.html)

> ```
>    -g, --grep=
>        Filter output to entries where the MESSAGE= field matches the
>        specified regular expression. PERL-compatible regular
>        expressions are used, see pcre2pattern(3) for a detailed
>        description of the syntax.
>
>        If the pattern is all lowercase, matching is case
>        insensitive. Otherwise, matching is case sensitive. This can
>        be overridden with the --case-sensitive option, see below.
> ```

Comment: This is what I was actually looking for. Having used the wrong search terms, I ended up here but found this. Thx.

Comment: this actually does not work, it match the message not the identifier field.

Comment: In fact you should be looking if `journalctl` was compiled with `systemd --version | grep "+PCRE2"`

Answer (score 1):

The original question titles "How do you use systemd's **journalctl patterns**". This points to a very specific feature of the journalctl called "MATCHES" rather than a generic regular expression filtering.

The "MATCHES" feature is fully detailed along with all other features at its friendly [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html) which states at its very beginning:

> If one or more match arguments are passed, the output is filtered
>   accordingly.

The "matches" feature is meant to filter the log entries out based upon a number of possible filters.

For cases like the one in the original question, this is how I do (I do run ArchLinux too).

First, you need to know the service name you are interested in. I usually do this:

```
systemctl | grep sshd
```

I get this:

```
sshd.service       loaded active running   OpenSSH Daemon
```

Then you can ask `journalctl` to filter by the "systemd unit name" like this:

```
journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service
```

It's called "the matches filtering". That'd be it.

In case the original question was written instead to mean "*how to apply `grep` to journalctl* output", then you can either apply `grep` to the logs stored "so far" with

```
journalctl | grep ssh
```

or look at the currently incoming log entries with

```
journalctl -f | grep ssh
```

and hit CTRL-C to stop the flow. Of course, you can use more complex pipes with either finer grained regular patterns or multiple `grep` commands.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but _SYTEMD_UNIT doesn't accept patterns. As mentioned in my comment and @Tim's answer, this was a bug in the docs.

Comment: @MarkGrimes, At least for me (systemd 239) it works. I always test what I say before writing it down. It works as documented.

Comment: The question is about using *patterns*, for example `ssh*`. The journalctl docs stated that this was possible at one time. The docs were incorrect and have been updated.

Comment: @MarkGrimes The question is about *systemd's journalctl patterns* not *any character pattern*. Please see my updated answer. And it works under ArchLinux exactly as documented.

Comment: You must be joking. I can't find an explanation of what PATTERN may be anywhere in that man page.

Comment: @reinierpost What does your systems says when you run `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service` ? Mine is filtering out the logs by that specific unit.

Comment: @EnzoR So is mine (and on my Ubuntu system, the service is called `ssh`), but how does that help us understand which patterns can be used?

Comment: @reinierpost No way AFAIK. I still prefer the old-fashioned text-based freely-available syslog. But I cannot fight the whole world. Documentation is lagging behind, at best, and is totally misleading and wrong at worst. Now the manpage says: `--identifier=SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER`. They removed the pattern and solved the problem.

Comment: @MarkGrimes There is another (*tongue in cheek*) bug in the docs for the `--unit` option. Current manual says `-u, --unit=UNIT|PATTERN ...` . I am not sure then how to query the journal if you don't have a precise unit name. Think for example about ssh/sshd. Without patterns you need to provide a precise match. And a prior scan of all the jorunal with a grep seems very inefficient and old-fashioned way of working.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needing to just find a term in journalctl, you open the logs with `journalctl -u <foo>`, then hit the `/` key. It'll open a prompt in the lower part of the terminal, and input the search term.
Journalctl will highlight all the occurrencies.

Answer (score -3):

You can define the unit file when you run `journalctl`.

> journalctl -f -u sshd.service

I will only show the journal of `sshd`

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question. The user is asking for using patterns in a filter.